# Change sound level when using earphones with iPhone dock

Tags: audio, music, iphone, ear-phones

When using Music on iPhone the user is able to use a slider to change the audio output level.

However, when the iPhone is docked in the official Apple dock, using the earphone jack in the back, the slider to change audio level is removed from the interface.

I would prefer to use the docks audio jack as it keeps the earphone wire on the surface of the desk rather than floating out the top of the phone over a keyboard and getting in the way.

Is there a way to make the audio level changeable when the iPhone is docked in the official iPhone dock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

Although it shares a connector type with headphones, the 1/8" mini stereo jack on the Apple iPhone dock is a line-level audio output. Its purpose is to connect the iPhone line out (part of the dock connector) to devices like amplified speakers, stereo amplifiers, etc. These devices provide their own volume control and (aside from fine-tuning of input levels) the assumption is that you don't want to have control over the sound level in two places.

Comment: That would be odd, seeing as iPods often sit in docks yet the sound is always two way. It just seems to be the iPhone dock. I'm yet to see someone plug that into another audio output. I just use it for clean desktop charging.

Comment: Anecdotally, I used the dock for line-level audio out all the time (stereo receiver, clock radio) before an amplified Bluetooth speaker and various AirPlay connections replaced the need. "Odd" as it may seem, understanding the signals available through the iPod dock connector make the design intent clear. Possibly adding to confusion: an iPod at full volume outputs a signal approximately equal to consumer line level through its headphone jack. For your purposes you could use 'phones with a built-in volume control or a headphone amp to achieve your goals.